# How to exec PROC with 1M records without hanging app and less time in C#

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, tcp

I am confusing about to choose the correct  software design model to write a efficient code  for the below scanario,

- I have a biometric device (socket communication) and the same device
  details like IP, etc  details are in the Database (SQL server 2012).
  Now the application (C#) need to

  1. connect to the device and
  2. Get the info for this device from DB.
  3. and Push into the same device. and Update the status result into the GUI.

and here, The devices are some time 100 Nos .

So for this I have done a code but that's not effectively doing this task, i mean taking more time to complete and very slow.

so far i did,

```
for(dev_count)
{
   if(check device is valid )
{
// read the device details 
 // Here creating thread and loading the emp details to device 
   Thread t1 = new Thread( loademptoDevice());
}

void loademptoDevice()
{
  // here connecting SQl connection and get teh details and load into device socket communication
}
```

- Like this I have coded but it giving poor response.

So I need someOne to give me good software design patter for to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the value of the lock method. Do you mind going into more detail on the use of the lock?

Comment: all threads are using same method to execute the procedure.  so for thread sync i am using lock keyword for that method

Comment: Why are you using multiple threads if you're still locking on a single DB connection? Are the threads doing something heavy? If so, having 100s running at the same time isn't that great. And if not the locking will make it run almost as a single thread anyway.

Comment: I forgot that point i.e) threading against SQL..  thank you

Answer (score 3):

Not enough info on your algorithm etc. but at a broad view, I believe that you are suffering from an issue related to your insertion.  SQL Server insert statements are fine for small data or largely varying sets, but what you are trying to do is a bulk insertion.  You will suffer an algorithmic issue in that every single insert statement is validated against your database's constraints.

You may need to look into use the SQL Bulk Copy API, or creating a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package for this.  That will perform the data writes in a single pass then validate the constraints using batches, which will increase your performance significantly.

Secondly, threading against SQL is pointless, as your IO will be 1000s of times slower than your disk.  You should have a single thread doing all of the database writing so that the database can then optimise the activity as much as possible.

Finally you are using hardware devices, I think there is a chance that you have a driver that simply isn't very performant.  I don't know if you are extracting the data as a single block or with a number of IO requests, but that will definitely slow your application down.  Have you tried measuring the time it takes to extract the data from a single device, then trying two threads in parallel and seeing if you have any improvement?  You may find that you are better off using only two threads, have one extracting the data, then having a second start to insert it as you extract it from the devices.  If parallel extraction does help, then scale up to the number of available CPU cores on your machine.

Comment: Thank you Spence for your valuable advice. I forgot that point i.e) threading against SQL.   by the way, Could you please explain when should I create nested threads  in what type of scenarios.

Comment: Best advice I can give you is measure then optimise.